# PS5 - How to request restricted game?

Tags: ps5

My son got a PS5 for Christmas and I’ve set him up an online account and profile on the console. Everything I’ve read says that to play a game rated older than his age he can request it.

So far, all we’ve tried is *Spider-Man Remastered* (which is a download from a code that came with *Spider-Man: Miles Morales* in case that’s relevant).

I can’t see anywhere he can request this game to be un-restricted, and when he tries to launch the game he only gets this message:

[image]

The only workaround I’ve found so far is to temporarily disable parental controls from my own profile but that undoes the next time we switch the console on.

How is this supposed to work? I’ve installed and signed into the PlayStation app on my phone so expected him to request it and I would receive some kind of notification or email.

Comment: Helpfull? https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/account/ps5-parental-controls-spending-limits/

Comment: @nobody. No. “ If your child tries to start a restricted game, the game will be blocked, and a screen appears. From here, your child can send a request for you to make an exception for the game.” As you can see on the screenshot I posted, no such option exists.

Comment: Having been used to the parental controls on the Switch - which are excellent - I find the PS5 ones to be totally confusing, at times contradictory, and seemingly someone thought the term “parental controls” means “prevent the parents from doing stuff”.

Comment: Hm are your son and you logged in at the same time?

Comment: @nobody not sure what you mean. We are both signed in online on our respective profiles, but obviously only one profile can be active at a time.

Comment: I have no experience with that. I thought only; maybe this option is blocked when more than one PS5 user are logged in at the same time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The workaround posted on [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS5/comments/jymmhr/parental_controls_cant_request_access_to_some/) worked:

> 1. In the child account, go to settings and use the Parental Setting key to temporarily disable Parental Controls
> 2. Still in the child account open the game and actually get as far as starting a new game.
> 3. Close the game using the switcher (I did this by switching to Astro's Playroom)
> 4. Still in the child account re-enable parental controls
> 5. Start the game again. The child will be able to request access.
> 6. Switch to the parent account and grant access.
> 7. Switch to the child account and try the game. If you have linked to an Ubisoft account you may now have to request access to
>    communications functions.
> 8. Switch to the parent account and grant access to communications functions.

Although it’s not ideal that you have to resort to a clunky workaround.

Comment: A nightmare, but it works

Comment: omg thats buggy as f*. Can confirm this is still needed, one year later - poor show from Sony

Comment: @OwenB Judging by the upvotes I’m still getting, it’s still relevant a whole year after that. We’re now in September 2023.

Comment: @Darren How can I do this if I dont have the game and am asking in the PS Shop? This does not work unless I have the game already.

Comment: @jhannrs How can you request to play the game before you have it? I don’t understand.